# run bash file in R : path in system() issue

Tags: r, bash, permissions, permission-denied

I am trying to run a bash file from inside R. So I have the following working fine:

```
setwd(path.expand("~/Documents/Rcode/"))

system("ls -F")
system('~/Documents/Rcode/GFR_test/run.sh')
```

So this works absolutely fine as I provided the whole path for the run.sh file. However, this gets tedious when working with long code and many bash files to run. So i needed to  create a variable for each sh file as:

```
myPATH <- "~/Documents/Rcode/GFR_test/"
```

then to call the run.sh

```
 system(paste(myPATH, 'run.sh'))
```

Unfortunately this does not work as I get the error:

```
 sh: 1: ~/Documents/Rcode/GFR_test/ : Permission denied
```

The permission issue is strange as I know I got it right. Can you please help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe replace `paste` with `paste0` ?

Comment: Hi Juba. I just tried it and it does work, perfect! Could you please tell me what is the diffrenec between paste and paste0?  Thanks again, you're a star.

Comment: Added as an answer. And, no, I'm not a star :-)

Comment: @katysmith Have you looked in the documentation to find the difference between those two functions?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `paste`, the default separator is a space. So :

```
paste(myPATH, 'run.sh')
```

would give :

```
~/Documents/Rcode/GFR_test/ run.sh
```

To suppress the extra space, you either have to add `sep=""` to your `paste()`, or, better, use `paste0` which has a default empty separator (and is a bit faster) :

```
paste0(myPATH, 'run.sh')
```